# RKMappingResult has objects, but they NSLog as null

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit, objective-c-blocks

**What I'm doing**

Using `RestKit`, I'm making a `GET` request to get a `JSON` object that contains an array of User objects that populate a `UITableView`.  I pass that array into a private `NSArray` called `users` which becomes `_users` (I'm still fuzzy on this).  This works, and the table populates fine.  I can access the individual objects in the `_users` array from my other methods, such as `[UITableViewCell cellForRowAtIndex]`.

However, at the same time I pull the data down, and before I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` from inside the `success` block of `[RKObjectManager getObjectsAtPath...]`, I want to process the individual objects a little bit.

**My problem**

Using `[RKObjectManager getObjectsAtPath parameters success failure]`, `success` returns the `RKMappingResult` as expected, and I pass its array to a `_users`, which populates my `UITableView`. This works, but in the same `success` block, I try `NSLog`'ing `_users[i]` and it returns `*nil description*`.  I know the values are being set at some point, because I populate my `UITableViewCells` by calling `_users[i]` in another method.

**Hopefully more helpful info**

When I `NSLog(@"%@", _users)` from inside the `success` block, and know for a fact there are 3 objects in the array, I see:

`(
    (null),
    (null),
    (null)
)`.

I can provide more info, I'm just not sure what to put.  I can also show my code, but it's basically out of the book from the RestKit docs.

**User object**

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fullName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bio;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *dob;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *avatar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *avatarMeta;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *enabled;

@end
```

**RKObjectManager example**

*note - some pieces have been removed for security reasons

```
- (void)loadUsers {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{@"token": self.token}];
    NSString *path = @"/api/v1/g/feed";
    if ( self.cursor ) {
        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path, self.cursor];
    }
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path
                                       parameters:params
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              _users = mappingResult.array;
                                              NSLog(@"Last User: %@",_users[0]); // *nil description*
                                              NSLog(@"Array: %@", _users); // ((null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null))
                                              [self.tableView reloadData]; // table gets populated correctly
                                          }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"No feed available: %@", error);
                                          }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're overriding the `description` method, probably by adding your own property with that name, in the user class and setting that to an empty string. This breaks everything. You should rename that property to `overview` or something like that and update your usage.

Comment: Hi @Wain, thanks for your help. I should have mentioned that I specifically changed the object key from `description` to `info` based on other SO posts similar to mine, and it did nothing to help.

Comment: Hi @wain, I've updated my original post with some code and info.  Please let me know if you'd like to see anything else.  Thanks.